Salt Deposits on Basement Brick Paint Surface and faulty Sseal around water supply pipe entry
I've noticed salt deposits appearing on the paint surface of the bricks in my basement. What are the specific factors or conditions that typically cause these salt deposits to form? I'm particularly interested in understanding the underlying causes so that I can effectively address and prevent this issue in the future.
The clay seal around the water supply pipe entry hole in my basement foundation wall is faulty, resulting in leaks during heavy rainfall. What is the best approach to repair or replace this seal effectively to ensure a lasting solution?
Thanks for all the advises.


Salt stains are dissolved minerals migrating through the masonry. This indicates moisture penetrating the external foundation seal if there is any. This is an annoyance but also indicative of your second problem.
There are companies that repair foundations that use epoxy injection to seal cracks that may also have a solution for cinder block.
An interim solution is to determine what the water sources are that contribute to ground saturation and divert that water away from the foundation. You should also ensure that the grade is sloping away from the foundation.
The longer term solution is to excavate around the foundation and apply a foundation barrier membrane. While you are at it, you should also inspect the drainage tile around the foundation footings for any blockage and that it is tied in to the storm water sewer system or sump pump.

Yep, a.k.a. efflorescence.

Thank you for the comments and information. I can tell the main water sources that contribute to ground saturation is rainfall. I will start to working on the interim and long term solution.
